# C# Winform Datagridview DataGridViewImageColumn Needs to be centered

Tags: datagridviewcolumn

this is my code :

```
((DataGridViewImageColumn)col).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
((DataGridViewImageColumn)col).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

[I would like to get the image centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAoTd.png)

any idea?